# Cannot get the correct field’s type on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a problem on Kibana, I converted a field from string to integer on the logstash configuration file using

```
if [exportedRecords]{
    mutate{
        convert => { "exportedRecords" => "integer" }
}
```

But when i get the field on kibana, i get it as a string.

What should i do ?

Best Regards.

Comment: Is this property in your index mapped as integer?

Comment: If the field has already been saved as a string in elasticsearch, the field is now mapped in elasticsearch as a string and all new instances of the field will be converted to a string. Either you use another field name, so that elasticsearch creates a new mapping for a new field, mapping it to integer, or you delete your index, so that mapping for this field is recreated as an integer.

Comment: i don't know what is mapping , i created my index automatically.. i didn't specify the type of the metric on kibana..